# Застряла с парой проблем, что бы не делала не помогает. С++ начала изучать совсем недавно

Tags: c++, qt

Застряла с парой проблем, что бы не делала не помогает. С++ начала изучать совсем недавно.

```
main.cpp

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "myserver.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    myserver Server;
    //Server.startServer();
    Server.incomingConnection();

    return a.exec();
}
```

myserver.cpp

```
void myserver::incomingConnection()
{
    char chr[200];
    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    //socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);
    socket->bind(17476);

    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(sockReady()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(sockDisc()));

    qDebug()<<socketDescriptor<<"Client connected";

    //"key":"value" or value
    //"type":"connect","status":"yes"}
    socket->write("{\"tupe\":\"connect\",\"status\":\"yes\"}");
    qDebug()<<"Send client connect status - Yes"<<sizeof(chr);
}


void UdpClient::slotProcessDatagrams()
{
    QByteArray daDatagram;

    //do
    {
        baDatagram.resize(m_pudp->pendingDatagramSize());
        m_pudp->readDatagram(baDatagram.data(), baDatagram.size());
    }
}

void myserver::sockDisc()
{

    qDebug()<<"Disconnect";
    socket->deleteLater();
}
```

И вот таки вот ошибки мне выбивает(

```
cpp:29: ошибка: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'QDebug' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>')
myserver.cpp:39: ошибка: 'UdpClient' has not been declared
myserver.cpp:45: ошибка: 'baDatagram' was not declared in this scope
myserver.cpp:45: ошибка: 'm_pudp' was not declared in this scope
```

myserver.h

```
#ifndef MYSERVER_H
#define MYSERVER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QDebug>

class myserver : public QUdpSocket
{

    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    myserver();
    ~myserver();

    QUdpSocket* socket;
    QByteArray Data;

public slots:
    //void startServer();
    void incomingConnection();
    void sockReady();
    void sockDisc();
};

#endif // MYSERVER_H
```

jsonserver.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2020-01-20T15:09:13
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui
QT       += network

TARGET = jsonserver
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    myserver.cpp

HEADERS += \
    myserver.h
```

Comment: Только недавно начали изучать и сразу надо клиент серверные приложения и ПО писать! Сначала основы изучите и научитесь понимать и переводить ошибки если не соображаете в английском.

Comment: Здесь: baDatagram на сколько вижу, у Вас опечатка. Это m_pudp  и это UdpClient - у Вас нигде, кажется, не объявлено....

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, это реализация примера из книги Шлее. Еще раз внимательно посмотрите, что находится у него в листинге. Вы пропустили приличное количество кода.

Answer (score 1):

cpp:29: ошибка: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'QDebug' and '')

в функции

```
void myserver::incomingConnection()
{
    char chr[200];
    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    //socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);
    socket->bind(17476);

    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(sockReady()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(sockDisc()));

    qDebug()<<socketDescriptor<<"Client connected";

    //"key":"value" or value
    //"type":"connect","status":"yes"}
    socket->write("{\"tupe\":\"connect\",\"status\":\"yes\"}");
    qDebug()<<"Send client connect status - Yes"<<sizeof(chr);
}
```

переменная socketDescriptor не определна, но она идет в вывод qDebug();

myserver.cpp:39: ошибка: 'UdpClient' has not been declared

в файле myserver.cpp

```
void myserver::incomingConnection()
{
    char chr[200];
    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    //socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);
    socket->bind(17476);

    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(sockReady()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(sockDisc()));

    qDebug()<<socketDescriptor<<"Client connected";

    //"key":"value" or value
    //"type":"connect","status":"yes"}
    socket->write("{\"tupe\":\"connect\",\"status\":\"yes\"}");
    qDebug()<<"Send client connect status - Yes"<<sizeof(chr);
}


void UdpClient::slotProcessDatagrams()
{
    QByteArray daDatagram;

    //do
    {
        baDatagram.resize(m_pudp->pendingDatagramSize());
        m_pudp->readDatagram(baDatagram.data(), baDatagram.size());
    }
}

void myserver::sockDisc()
{

    qDebug()<<"Disconnect";
    socket->deleteLater();
}
```

функция

```
void UdpClient::slotProcessDatagrams()
```

должна иметь вид

```
void myserver::slotProcessDatagrams()
```

myserver.cpp:45: ошибка: 'baDatagram' was not declared in this scope

```
void UdpClient::slotProcessDatagrams()
{
    QByteArray daDatagram;

    //do
    {
        baDatagram.resize(m_pudp->pendingDatagramSize());
        m_pudp->readDatagram(baDatagram.data(), baDatagram.size());
    }
}
```

объявлена **d**aDatagram используется несуществующее **b**aDatagram

myserver.cpp:45: ошибка: 'm_pudp' was not declared in this scope

m_pudp не определен, очевидно название переменной должно быть socket